# Java Match 2 strings like grepl in R

Tags: java

In R, I have 2 strings which when I grepl give me TRUE.

```
grepl("KREDITO ?24" , "Kredito24", ignore.case = TRUE)
```

However In Java I have to do something similar.

I cannot use

```
str1.equals(str2)
```

or

```
str1.contains(str2)
```

because they will give me false. 
What Can I use in Java. I am confused because there is no grepl. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your WHOLE code please. I can't tell you what to use just by you giving a one-liner...

Comment: -4 does seem to be unjustified, but then so is +3 (presumably from kind people who are compensating). You are therefore in credit for a question that I would not have voted either way. Anyway, my advice is not to worry about it. If you want to ask people why they have downvoted, please do so in the comments - note that future readers outnumber voters considerably, and in a year or two any voting commentary in the body of the question won't be of interest to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `matches` so that it would accept regex as an argument. Likewise, first argument in grepl is a regex so this must be included as an argument to matches function.

```
"Kredito24".matches("(?i)KREDITO ?24");
```

or

```
str1.matches("(?i)"+str2);
```

`(?i)` ignore case modifier or case-insensitive modifier.

Comment: HI Avinash, I tried your solution but I get the following error: 
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index